# How to do recursive templates in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, tree, mustache

rather a theoretical question - how can I render recursive templates in Meteor? For example, displaying a comment on comment with unlimited number of comment sub-levels so that HTML would be diplayed as the following?

```
<section>
   some text
   <section>
      nested text
      <section>
        further nested text and sections
        .....
      </section>
   </section>
</section>
```

In my case I pass to the "tree" template a mongoDB document and this document can have unlimited number of sub-content levels. My example below doesn't work the way I want.

```
<template name="tree">  
    <div class="wrapper" style="border:1px solid red">
        <ul>
            {{#each getStructure}}
            <li>
                {{#each content}}
                <ul>

                    <li>
                        <a class="item">{{text}}</a>

                        <!-- TODO: this stuff needs to be recursive. 
                        {{#if sub_content}}
                        <ul>
                            {{#each sub_content}}
                                <li>
                                <a class="item">{{text}}</a>
                                {{#if sub_content}}
                                ....
                                {{/if}}
                                </li>
                            {{/each}}
                        </ul>
                        {{/if}}
                    </li>

                </ul>
                {{/each}}
            </li>

            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simplified example of recirsuve, say you had a post sample template of:

```
<template name="post">
  {{post_text}}

  {{#each comments}}
    {{>comment}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

and a post helper of:

```
Template.post.helpers({
  comments: function() {
    return CommentCollection.find({post_id: this._id, parent_id: {$exists: 0}});
  }
});
```

I would create a template for the comment layout and provide a helper in that for sub-comments, depending on your data structure something like the following:

```
<template name="comment">
  {{comment_text}}

  {{#each sub_comment}}
    {{> comment}}
  {{/each}}

</template>
```

and then the helper along the lines of:

```
Template.comment.helpers({
  sub_comments: function() {
    return CommentCollection.find({parent_id: this._id});
  }
});
```

This would recursively produce the comments template for each sub-comment then roll back up the tree to the next `#each` and then print that comment and all of its sub-comments etc.

Comment: Thanks Aaron. Your reply is spot on, however I found out that my problem was not with the template itself but with the app crashing on complex data. You seem to be a knowlegeable person in Meteor and Hanlebars - could you please look at my other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27364206/meteor-throws-exception-exception-from-tracker-recompute-function-too-much-rec

Comment: This demo was extremely helpful.