# Meteor throws exception: Exception from Tracker recompute function: too much recursion

Tags: recursion, meteor, handlebars.js

I have a recursive template in a Meteor application that builds tree structure with unlimited levels. The template works ok with small trees but when I test application on real data with many tree levels then I get the following two exceptions in console and no part of the tree gets rendered:

```
> Exception from Tracker recompute function: Node was not found
> meteor....3d493c5 (line 883)
> 
> Exception from Tracker recompute function: too much recursion
> _.forEach@http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?0a80a8623e1b40b5df5a05582f288ddd586eaa18:156:7
> ClassHandler<.parseValue@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?77c0809654ee3a10dcd5a4f961fb1437e7957d33:1115:5
> DiffingAttributeHandler<.update@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?77c0809654ee3a10dcd5a4f961fb1437e7957d33:1084:9
> etc. This is a very long stack
```

I'm not sure what "Node was not found" exception is about. I added it to the post because it seems to be related to the next one, which makes more sense. Is there a way to fix this?

**UPDATE:**

The amount of levels is actually not very large - the deepest branch is less than 10 levels. Also, I just noticed that the tree does get rendered in Chrome. The browser I see bug in is IceWeasel/Firefox 32.1.0 on Debian Linux.

Comment: Yep, this kind of issue has been discussed a lot of times. What happens is that sometimes Blaze has to do a vast amount of recursions even if it doesn't look like what you are doing is breaking the roof.

See [this](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform/issues/333) about aldeed:autoform for example.

Thing is, Firefox has a couple issues with Blaze. Everything will work fine with most browsers, but Firefox may sometimes crash for no particular reason, particularly on Linux.

Comment: Thanks Kyll. A bug in framework core discovered after 2 weeks of development... too bad